# How can I get a bitshift number based off of an integer

Tags: java, int, bitwise-operators, bit-shift

So, I have a tile size inter (which is 8, right now, I have it a global variable in case i decide to change my tile size) and in my main render method i get the the tile by saying

```
for (int xTile = xOffset >> 3; xTile <= (xOffset + width) >> 3; xTile)
```

How can I get the 3 based of my tile size which is 8?

Edit: or if i change my tile size to 16, i would like the 3 to be a 4

Comment: Use a constant instead of hardcoding the numbers.

Comment: i have a constant for my tilesize I was just looking for conversion to initialize a constant for tilesizebitshift.

Answer (score 2):

Use two constants.

```
public static final int SHIFT = 3;
public static final int TILE_SIZE = 2 << SHIFT;
```